# Spring boot Websocket with stomp js: I keep getting Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/ws

Tags: spring-websocket, sockjs

I want to integrate chatting into an application I made, and after following some tutorials and running the application I keep getting "Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/ws" on my console I tried  using sockjs path as"/ws" but still got the same error, please can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong ?

here is the snippet of my code:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {

        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
                .withSockJS();

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/message");

    }
}
```

and this is my client

```
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');

stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);

function onConnected() {

    console.log("its working");

}


function onError(error) {

    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Were you ever able to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

i am not sure about the `CustomHandshakeHandler` which you are using here. so that might be an issue to look into. also, consider to add `.setAllowedOrigins("*")` to your stompEndpointRegistry.

apart from that, the code looks ok and should work IMO.

Comment: .setAllowedOrigins("*") was the right answer in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio emulator, try using http://10.0.2.2:8080/ws