# Can´t establish connection to websocket "Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080"

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I´m trying to implement a websocket in my spring boot application, but I´m unable to create a connection.

I used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UP0GJPpMV3c) and its corresponding [git-repo](https://github.com/caligula95/tic-tac-toe) to create the following config for the server and the javascript code for the client.

### **Server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gameplay");
        registry.addEndpoint("/gameplay").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

### **Client**

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8080';
let stompClient;
let paymentId;

function connectToSocket() {
    console.log("Trying to open connection to /gameplay");
    let socket = new SockJS("/gameplay");
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log("connected to the frame: " + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe("/topic/game-progress", function (response) {
            console.log("data");
            let data = JSON.parse(response.body);
            console.log(data);
        })
    })
}
```

The server-console doesn´t have any entries, so I guess there is something wrong with the javascript part. In the browser-console it says:

```
Trying to open connection to /gameplay
Opening Web Socket...
GET http://localhost:8080/gameplay/info?t=1620312392571 404
Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/gameplay
```

### **I tried...**

1. using different URLs to establish the connection

   - http://localhost:8080/gameplay
   - http://localhost:8080/app/gameplay
   - /gameplay
   - /app/gameplay
2. Using the URLs from the first bullet point to establish a connection using Chrome´s advanced REST client. I got the message "Unknown error occured"
3. Adding .setAllowedOrigins("*") to my stompEndpointRegistry like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170970/spring-boot-websocket-with-stomp-js-i-keep-getting-whoops-lost-connection-to-h)

### **Does anyone know...**

1. Where the last part of the request (/info?t=1620312392571 )comes from and could it be causing the malfunction?
2. If I need to write "http:localhost.8080" before the socket URL? Some people [do that](https://github.com/caligula95/tic-tac-toe/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/js/socket_js.js), [others don´t](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring).
3. How I can get this working?

In others questions the root of the problem had something to do with the dependencies. I included all the dependencies that fixed the problem for other users so I. don´t think the dependencies are the problem. However, here is a link to my [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/BlairBass/7d9f83a6ba0cf76e319d088f699fd927).

I´m thankful for all kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. Update client code as

```
let socket = new SockJS("/app/gameplay");
```

Don't modify below server code

```
registry.addEndpoint("/gameplay").withSockJS();
```